# jquery, javascript сортировка массива по ключу и букве

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходима помощь в сортировке массив типа:

```
var array = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name:"simple",
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name:"prisimple",
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name:"Simples",
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        name:"mysimples",
    }]
```

Отсортировать нужно по полю name, и предустановленной букве.
Если предустановленная буква равна "**s**", то результат должен быть таков:

```
Simples,
simple,
mysimples,
prisimple.
```

А если буква "**m**", то:

```
mysimples,
prisimple,
Simples,
simple
```

Нашел такой пример сортировки(для буквы '**s**'):

```
var sortArray = array.sort(function(a, b) {
      var bx = b.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('s');
      var ax = a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('s');
      bx = bx === -1 ? 9000 : bx;
      ax = ax === -1 ? 9000 : ax;
      return ax - bx;
    });
```

Получается сортировать, но не учитывается большая или маленькая буква. А мне необходимо в начале выводить с большой буквы.

Comment: Замечательно, задание мы поняли. Напишите, как Вы пытались его выполнить.

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой и ответ. Смотрите в сторону lodash.